# Drupal 7 - Create page with data retrieved from db

Tags: drupal-7

I am developing a site with Drupal 7.
I collect some data from visitors and store them in a custom table in drupal db.
That data are related to an association, with address, contacts and some other info.
That data are only stored in db, but not displaied in the site.
What I want to do is create a custom content type, in which I choose an association via a select field and retrieve the data from db.
With that data I wanto to "embed" them in a html code, without re-entering the information.
Is it possible to do that?

I hope that my question is clear.

Thanks in advance,
Mauro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, time has come to create your [first Drupal Module](http://reinholdweber.com/2010/06/28/create-your-first-simple-drupal-7-module/) .

1. Create module files (module.info, module.module , module.install )
2. Use [Schema module](http://drupal.org/project/schema) to examine your custom table and provide you the hook_schema() you need in your .install file
3. Create a hook_menu() to create the path you need for your page e.g mydrupal.com/custompage
4. In custompage callback function , query your database using the [best practices](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/group/database/7) and return your data

for the custom content types and configurable theming you need to go even further and take advantage of the [node_api](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/group/node_api_hooks/7) and theming hooks and functions

Hope this helped

Comment: Thank Pan, but I solved using the ajax method of form_alter, using a callback to "pre-load" the body with a html markup of data I want to display.